# wifi one or the other

Tags: lumia

To connect new devices to my router I have to make the router wireless setting visible, connect the device (enter router password) and then I can set the router wireless back to invisible.  Has worked for numerous wifi devices.
I have two lumnia 520 phones.   The first one was connected to the router a few years ago and is working fine on wifi.   The second one was disconnected about 6 months ago.  I want to reconnect the second one back to the router.  The phone saw the router but I was unable to connect to it.  So I deleted the router wifi network on the phone, set the router wireless to visible and connected the phone just fine.  The problem is when I set the router wireless to invisible, the second phone then loses it connection to the router network.  I have cycled the power on the phone, turned off blu tooth and automatic software updates.  Nothing seems to help.   Looking for advice on what to try next.   Thanks.

Comment: Is the primary microsoft account for both phones the same? Do you have WiFi Sense set to share your WiFi connections?

Comment: account is the same.  WiFi sense is off because I want to use my secure network at home.

Comment: Odd. On my phones, where I've signed in witht he same acccount, they all know about the same networks, and all connect to all of them.